# Load sa saved form template into sharepoint

Tags: infopath

We have an issue where we can no longer publish to Sharepoint from InfoPath. I have saved the form template and have access to Sharepoint Designer. Is it possible using sharepoint designer to say I want to use that form template as my edit and new forms?

We are currently using Sharepoint 2010 and InfoPath 2013. Publish was working up until about a month ago and the sharepoint admins are not sure how to fix it, so need alternative methods.